# Issue while accessing data from Octave dataframe

Tags: octave

I am trying to access data from a dataframe in Octave which satisfy some criterias.

Let us say dataframe name is A with comulns 'Date' and 'Close Price'.

Let us say we intend to access Close prices when Close Price was less than 5.

I am using the command:

> > A.Close(A.Close<5)

I am getting the following error:

> > error: subsref.m querying name Close returned positions 5
> > subsref.m querying name  returned positions

I see an instruction video in youtube, where same command is used but no error showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem. Are you sure your dataframe is correctly initialised?

```
pkg load dataframe
A = dataframe( [1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8], 'colnames', { 'Date', 'Close Price' } );
A.Close( A.Close < 5 )
% ans =
%    2
%    4
```

I suspect your error may have to do with the fact that your column name is `Close_Price`, but you tried to index it via 'Close'. Do you have any other columns that start with the word 'Close' by any chance?

Comment: no, it is not the case. I did a typo in question text. even more surprising is in the data frame I am able to access othe columns with this form of command, (say, A.open(1:10) works, and it also works for other columns). but as soon as I try to  access A.close, it given an error mentioning subsref.m. I dont think compiler could not find the column because it tells me the exact column number in the error message.

Comment: I think "querying name Close returned positions 5" means that there are five candidates for the string 'Close' to choose from. I.e. there is no column such that this substring can be matched to uniquely. e.g. if you add another column in my example called "Close Call", you'll get this error with "positions 2"

Comment: when I execute A.colnames I set the names:
"" Date, 
Open, 
High, 
Low, 
Close, 
Adj_Close, 
Volume.""   

When I execute A.Open, or any other column name which is not 'Close' everything is normal. But as soon as I write A.Close I get this error message:  

"" error: subsref.m querying name Close returned positions 5
subsref.m querying name  returned positions
error: called from
    subsref at line 87 column 21""

Comment: I see. What seems to be happening is you have two variables that contain the word "Close". Therefore using "Close" to match only a single column name fails, because the substring matches two names: `Close`, and `Adj_Close`. However, I agree with you that in this case, since 'Close' matches the name of a column _exactly_, it should have disregarded other partial matches, so I would treat this as a bug. Perhaps this has been reported and fixed in development already ... I'll have a look. Otherwise I'll file a bug. In the meantime, as a workaround, index the column by number (or change the name).

Comment: Nope. Same bug exists in development. I'll open a bug on the bug tracker :)

Comment: Bug reported as [bug #60210](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60210) on the octave bug tracker.

Comment: @Harish incidentally, looking at the code of @dataframe/subsref, if you go to line 76 of the current release, where it says `indi = strmatch (S(1).subs, resu.x_name{2}, 'exact');`, uncomment that line, and then comment out the next one, then this seems to replace 'partial' matching with 'exact' matching, which may be what you want.   (if you're using the dev version, the equivalent line is line 83). Perhaps this might work for you as a workaround. :)